# Android how to stop music when screen is off

Tags: android, audio-player, screen-off, android-music-player

My music stop when I press home button but when the screen is off it is playing. How can I stop this? And restore when the screen is on.

Comment: stop the music in `onPause`. restore it in `onResume`

Comment: yes but if I do this music will be stop when I open new Activity. I don't want this.

Comment: then what do you want? What do you mean by screen is off?

Comment: When I play power button and screen goes off I want that musis also stop

Comment: screen lock an unlock??

Comment: yes if screen is lock, music stop

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for details on what makes a good question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to programmatically register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the [`ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) and [`ACTION_SCREEN_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) intent actions. You can **not** register a receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml for these actions.

```
private BroadcastReceiver screenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
};

// to register the receiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
context.registerReceiver(screenOffReceiver, filter);
```

Hopefully you are playing music in a `Service`, in which case you can register the screen off receiver when your music starts. `Service` extends `Context`, so you can call `registerReceiver` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service in background, create a single instance of soundPlayer. In the service check which is the Activity in focus. If the package does not belong to your Application, then stop  the music.